# Accept auto-correct suggestion with one keystroke

Tags: macos, keyboard, auto-complete, autocorrect

Sometimes, there's an auto-correct suggestion I want to accept, but I don't want to type a period or space followed by a delete. Nor do I want to hit down arrow, return. (That's incredibly lazy of me, now that I think about it.)

Is there any way, barring macro apps, to do this with one keystroke?

Comment: To clarify: "macro apps" include Keyboard Maestro, Typonator, TextExpander, and the like.

Comment: How about Automator? Is that out also?

Comment: @DanielL Yes. Ideally, I'm looking for something that's set up right out of the box.

Comment: Another factor is trying to accept a suggestion when you've added letters to the beginning of the word, such that your cursor is not at the end of it. In that case, the autocorrect suggestion pops up but period or space won't choose it. Not the same as your question, but worth noting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have 69 non-modifier keys on my MacBook Air and 9 modifier keys. Having worked my way through all 78 single keystrokes possible on my keyboard, I can say with confidence that none of them have the effect of both accepting the autocorrect suggestion **and** not producing any input on your system. If you are looking for a single key press, the answer is definitively, as set up out of the box, no this cannot be done. Once you open the door for multiple key presses, there are options, as you acknowledge, but if your standard is a single key press, **no, it cannot be done.**

Comment: Excellent thorough research! :D